# Spacing between numbers and text in text mode

Tags: spacing, text

I am puzzled by the appearance of this tiny piece of text:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
    12 to 15
\end{document}
```

It depends a little on the zoom level, but it's probably not just me who notices that the space between `2` and `t` is smaller than the space between `o` and `1`. I know that LaTeX has monospace digits, but I was not aware that this extended beyond math mode.

Is there anything that one can do so typeset digits with a more balanced space around them?

[image]

[image]

Comment: the default math setup uses digits from the default set font so they are exactly the same in text and math. the extra space is the left sidebearing of `1` so you can preceded `1 by `\kern-something` with some size to taste but it is not very automatic. the lm fonts have proportional digits, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/247530/difference-between-cfr-lm-and-lm-package/247543#247543

Comment: Would this `\kern-something` depend on the character that **precedes** `1`, `2` etc. or could the correct value be figured out once for each digit?

Comment: mostly you could just use a fixed value (to equalize the sidebrearings)  although optical effects of adjacent character shapes may mean you still want to add additional inter-character kerns just as happens in normal text.

Answer (score 3):

If Latin Modern is acceptable as a substitution for Computer Modern, you can use `cfr-lm` to access proportional figures as explained in the answer David linked to.

[image: 12 to 15]

The tabular and proportional figures match in the case of the typewriter font since `monowidth` selects the mono-spaced typewriter option.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[rm={lining,proportional},sf={lining,proportional},tt={lining,tabular,monowidth}]{cfr-lm}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tabular}{ll}
    12 to 15    &   proportional\\

    {\tstyle 12 to 15}  &   tabular\\

    \textsf{12 to 15}   &   proportional\\

    \textsf{\tstyle 12 to 15}   &   tabular\\

    \texttt{12 to 15}   &   tabular\\

    \texttt{\pstyle 12 to 15}   &   proportional\\
  \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```